# why cannot get rid of first word after white space and brackets with sub, in R?

Tags: r, tidyverse, gsub

I am trying to get rid of:

1. white space and/or words after first word and;
2. want to get rid of brackets after the first words
3. or just keep the first words in columns

Here it is the type of dataset I have:

```
structure(list(med_name = c("Co-amoxiclav", "doxycycline", "Gentamicin", 
"Co-trimoxazole", "Sodium Chloride 0.9% infusion (ANES) 20 mL + Vancomycin", 
"Piperacillin + Tazobactam (contains penicillin)"), new1 = c("Co-amoxiclav", 
"doxycycline", "Gentamicin", "Co-trimoxazole", "Sodium Chloride", 
"Piperacillin + Tazobactam (contains penicillin)"), new2 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, "Vancomycin", "Tazobactam (contains penicillin)")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

with the bellow code, I believe I get rid of the first words after white spaces and the words in the brackets. Actually want to keep the first word only in each column new_1 and new_2

```
dt_test_1 <- dt_test %>%
  dplyr::mutate(keep_first_letter_new_1 = gsub(' [A-z ]*', "", new1), 
                keep_first_letter_new_2 = gsub(' [A-z]*', "", new2), 
                remove_brackets_new_1 = gsub("( )", "", keep_first_letter_new_1), 
                remove_brackets_new_2 = gsub("( )", "", keep_first_letter_new_2)
                )
```

Yet as observed in the dt_test_1 - I do not get the output I want. Check the last two columns, and the last rows in each column. Here is what I get:

```
structure(list(med_name = c("Co-amoxiclav", "doxycycline", "Gentamicin", 
"Co-trimoxazole", "Sodium Chloride 0.9% infusion (ANES) 20 mL + Vancomycin", 
"Piperacillin + Tazobactam (contains penicillin)"), new1 = c("Co-amoxiclav", 
"doxycycline", "Gentamicin", "Co-trimoxazole", "Sodium Chloride", 
"Piperacillin + Tazobactam (contains penicillin)"), new2 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, "Vancomycin", "Tazobactam (contains penicillin)"), 
    keep_first_letter_new_1 = c("Co-amoxiclav", "doxycycline", 
    "Gentamicin", "Co-trimoxazole", "Sodium", "Piperacillin+(contains)"
    ), keep_first_letter_new_2 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "Vancomycin", 
    "Tazobactam(contains)"), remove_brackets_new_1 = c("Co-amoxiclav", 
    "doxycycline", "Gentamicin", "Co-trimoxazole", "Sodium", 
    "Piperacillin+(contains)"), remove_brackets_new_2 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, "Vancomycin", "Tazobactam(contains)")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Thus, my question is, why I do not get the output I want?

This is my desired output:

```
structure(list(med_name = c("Co-amoxiclav", "doxycycline", "Gentamicin", 
"Co-trimoxazole", "Sodium Chloride 0.9% infusion (ANES) 20 mL + Vancomycin", 
"Piperacillin + Tazobactam (contains penicillin)"), new1 = c("Co-amoxiclav", 
"doxycycline", "Gentamicin", "Co-trimoxazole", "Sodium Chloride", 
"Piperacillin + Tazobactam (contains penicillin)"), new2 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, "Vancomycin", "Tazobactam (contains penicillin)"), 
    keep_first_letter_new_1 = c("Co-amoxiclav", "doxycycline", 
    "Gentamicin", "Co-trimoxazole", "Sodium", "Piperacillin+(contains)"
    ), keep_first_letter_new_2 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "Vancomycin", 
    "Tazobactam(contains)"), remove_brackets_new_1 = c("Co-amoxiclav", 
    "doxycycline", "Gentamicin", "Co-trimoxazole", "Sodium", 
    "Piperacillin"), remove_brackets_new_2 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    "Vancomycin", "Tazobactam")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

The last two columns are the final ones I need.

Comment: You should precise the question to get a straightforward answer. Your regexps are off in general: 1) `gsub(' [A-z ]*', "", new1)` removes all sequences of a space and then zero or more spaces, ASCII letters and also ``[\`]^_`` chars, and 2) `gsub("( )", "", keep_first_letter_new_1)` removes all spaces.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - I am a newbie into the natural language processing and hard  to be specific

Comment: Do you realize all your first 3 points are about just keeping the first word? `sub(" .*", "", x)` is all that you need judging by those requirements.

Comment: Please think about the real requirements before posting them.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yet, that is a question in different circumstances. I have provided the problem, I have provided the code I am working with, I also provided the output and then the desired answer. I do believe there should be a leverage you leave for the newbies to learn and the best way to learn is not confuse them :). Just go on my fake datasets given and see how clear I was, regardless of the concepts not used (again I am a newbie in regex). But if proves you did not go and checked. Sitting on the side and judge the hard work behind creating this post isn't the way it should work.

Answer (score -1):

In the following code, `x` is just the first data structure you provided. I found it easier to split the strings by the "+" sign and then extract the first word. The surrounding spaces can be trimmed via `str_trim` from the `stringr` package.

```
med=x$med_name
library(stringr)
strings=str_split(med, "\\+")
out=lapply(strings, function(x) {
  str_trim(str_extract(x, " *(\\S*)"))}
)
out
[[1]]
[1] "Co-amoxiclav"

[[2]]
[1] "doxycycline"

[[3]]
[1] "Gentamicin"

[[4]]
[1] "Co-trimoxazole"

[[5]]
[1] "Sodium"     "Vancomycin"

[[6]]
[1] "Piperacillin" "Tazobactam"

new_1=c()
new_2=c()
for (i in 1:6) {
  new_1[i]=out[[i]][1]
  new_2[i]=out[[i]][2]
}        
transform(x[-c(2,3)], new_1=new_1, new_2=new_2)

                                                 med_name          new_1      new_2
1                                            Co-amoxiclav   Co-amoxiclav       <NA>
2                                             doxycycline    doxycycline       <NA>
3                                              Gentamicin     Gentamicin       <NA>
4                                          Co-trimoxazole Co-trimoxazole       <NA>
5 Sodium Chloride 0.9% infusion (ANES) 20 mL + Vancomycin         Sodium Vancomycin
6         Piperacillin + Tazobactam (contains penicillin)   Piperacillin Tazobactam
```

Comment: is this on my own datasets on you made one? And then applied the answer?

Comment: It used the dataset that you pasted under "Here is the type of dataset I have:"

Comment: my apologies to this! I see this now. I am then sorry for marking this down! Cheers.

Comment: I have to take my word back, it did not work as I have 250 different levels  and alll are in very different shapes and forms.

Answer (score -1):

It seems there is an order that I missed when attempting to perform all the trims of unwanted characters. Thus, I believe the mistake is that I get rid of white spaces above and then the words in brackets become one word with the first word. Then when I apply to get rid of the words in the brackets I do not succeed as there is no white space in between the words.

I am therefore, keep a specific order in getting rid of unwanted characters and words:

1. I remove the white space but
2. Add a new one - the one that removes hyphens between the words and then
3. I am getting rid of the second word after the first one.

Here is what I have done to resolve my issues posted above:

```
  dt_test_1 <- dt_test %>%
      dplyr::mutate(keep_first_letter_new_1 = gsub(' [A-z ]*', "", new1), 
                    keep_first_letter_new_2 = gsub(' [A-z]*', "", new2), 
                    remove_hypen_new_1 = gsub("-", "", keep_first_letter_new_1), 
                    remove_hypen_new_2 = gsub("-", "", keep_first_letter_new_2), 
                    remove_any_words_after_first_new1 =    gsub("\\s([^\\)]+\\)",remove_hypen_new_1, "", remove_hypen_new_1), 
                    remove_any_words_after_first_new2 = gsub("\\s([^\\)]+\\)",remove_hypen_new_1, "", remove_hypen_new_2))
```